# What does (provide = true) do in GWT?

Tags: gwt

In the xml file, I have some fields like:

```
<ui:with field="f1" type="t1"/>
```

In the correlated Java file, I need to use:

```
@UiField( provided = true ) Type t1 = ...;
```

so that my project won't fail. So what does `(provide = true)` do in GWT? And why we need to manually write `(provided = true)` in the Jave file?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `provided` parameter denotes, that the field's widget must not be created by UIBinder, but is provided by your code.

```
@UIField Button btnUIbinder;
@UIField(provided=true) Button btnYourCode;

public YourClassConstructor() {
    btnYourCode = new Button(...); // required!

    // init uibinder here 

}
```

The `provided` keyword supports widgets with complex creation procedures. Or situations, where you already have the widget from another source.